# Renaming directories and files in a loop Python

Tags: python

I would like to go through a folder and its subfolder to rename the files and folders/subfolders that match a certain pattern with another new pattern(ie,replace "test" with "practice" in the folder names and file names).
I have a screen where the user enters in the root folder name, pattern to be found, pattern to be replaced. However, when I am executing the code to walk through the folders to rename them it gives an error:
a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tk
What am I doing wrong?
--code---

```
import os, shutil,fnmatch
import re
from posixpath import dirname
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.tix import DirSelectDialog

fields = 'Folder', 'Search', 'Replace', 'Pattern to Replace'

def fetch(entvals):
    #print entvals
    #print ents
    entItems = entvals.items()
    for entItem in entItems:
        field = entItem[0]
        text  = entItem[1].get()
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))

def findReplace(entvals):
    #print ents
    excl_dirs = {'i18n', 'target','ui.tests', '.settings','.github', '.structure'}
    directory = entvals.get("Folder").get()
    find = entvals.get("Search").get()
    new_name = entvals.get("Replace").get()
    filePattern = entvals.get("Pattern to Replace").get()
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory),topdown=False):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in excl_dirs]
        for file_name in files:
            new_name = file_name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
            if (new_name != file_name):
                os.rename(os.path.join(root, file_name), os.path.join(root, new_name))

        for dir_name in dirs:
            new_name = dir_name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
            if (new_name != dir_name):
                os.renames(os.path.join(root, dir_name), os.path.join(root, new_name))

        #print(path)
        #for dir_name in fnmatch.filter(dirs,new_name):
            #new_name = dir_name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
            #print(dir_name)
            #if (new_name != dir_name):
            #    os.renames(os.path.join(root, dir_name), os.path.join(root, new_name))
        print("----renamed------")

        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            #print(filepath)  
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
        print("----done changing files----")
             
    print("----done-------")


def makeform(root, fields):
    entvals = {}
    for field in fields:
        row = Frame(root)
        lab = Label(row, width=17, text=field+": ", anchor='w')
        ent = Entry(row)
        row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
        entvals[field] = ent
    #print ent
    return entvals

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Recursive S&R")
    ents = makeform(root, fields)
    # print ents
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
    b1 = Button(root, text='Show', command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
    b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b2 = Button(root, text='Execute', command=(lambda e=ents: findReplace(e)))
    b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b3 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
    b3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
root = Tk()

os.rename(os.path.join(root, file_name), os.path.join(root, new_name))
```

`root` is a Tk object.  You cannot pass that into `os.path.join()`.

Comment: thank you. so dumb question because I am new to python would it be: os.rename(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join(path, new_name)) ?

Comment: @CarolynKlein I think so.

Comment: yes @JohnGordon, it worked! thank you for the help. I also removed the circular reference that was causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing exactly what the error complains about: passing the tkinter.Entry instead of a string or something that can be understood as a path.
Shameless copy from http://tkdocs.com/widgets/entry.html

> How do I...
> Get the current value?    Look at the linked variable, or use the "get" method.

The Entry isn't just text. Position, state, font, size... You have to give python a hint want from such a complex object